# Counting elements that satisfy a criteria in a dataset- Python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataset

In a dataset, I have four columns named TP1, TP2 etc (stands for Testing Phase 1,2...). The information in these columns can be one of the following 5: *Not_tested, Not_finished, too_low, a value between 150 and 190, and nothing.*

An element is considered tested when it shows at least once, in any of the 4 columns, the values: too_low or a value between 150 and 190. If neither of these 2 is showed at any point in the row for that element, then it is considered not tested.

I need to report something like:

"Number of tested elements: 43 (and a percentage from all elements)" (which equates to how many rows show *too_low* or *a value between 150 and 190*)

"Number of new tested elements: # and %" (so from the elements found above, which have a *YES* in the **NEW** column?)

"Number of old tested elements: # and %" (which have a *NO* instead)

An example of part of the dataset is present here below:

```
+=======+==========+=====+======+==============+=========+==============+=====+
|  ID   | Location | NEW | YEAR |     PT1      |   PT2   |     PT3      | PT4 |
+=======+==========+=====+======+==============+=========+==============+=====+
| GF342 | Q1       | YES | 2021 |              |         |              |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| IF874 | Q3       | NO  | 2018 | NOT_TESTED   |         | TOO_LOW      |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| FH386 | Q1       | NO  | 2019 |              |         |              |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| KJ190 | Q3       | YES | 2021 | NOT_FINISHED |         | TOO_LOW      |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| TY748 | Q3       | YES | 2021 |              |         |              |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| YT947 | Q4       | NO  | 2019 |              | TOO_LOW |              | 165 |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| DF063 | Q3       | NO  | 2019 | 180          |         |              |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| ET512 | Q1       | YES | 2021 |              |         |              |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| GC714 | Q2       | NO  | 2018 |              | 160     |              |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| SD978 | Q3       | NO  | 2019 |              | TOO_LOW |              |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| EF472 | Q1       | NO  | 2018 |              |         |              |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| PL489 | Q2       | YES | 2021 |              |         | NOT_FINISHED |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| AZ315 | Q1       | NO  | 2018 | TOO_LOW      |         |              | 180 |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| OL821 | Q1       | YES | 2021 |              |         | 185          |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| HN765 | Q3       | YES | 2021 | 155          |         |              |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
| ED589 | Q1       | YES | 2021 |              |         | 165          |     |
+-------+----------+-----+------+--------------+---------+--------------+-----+
```

My idea to solve this problem was to use .sum() of all rows containing the necessary values, but how do I make a rule that it is only counted if present with these values? Could I maybe add a new column to the dataframe with T or F depending on if it satisfies the rule of having too_low or a number (150-190). I am quite new to all this and not sure how to go about it. I am not necessarily for a straight answer but some guidance on the problem if possible, thank you.

**Dataframe:**

```
pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 'GF342',  1: 'IF874',  2: 'FH386',  3: 'KJ190',  4: 'TY748',  5: 'YT947',  6: 'DF063',  7: 'ET512',  8: 'GC714',  9: 'SD978',  10: 'EF472',  11: 'PL489',  12: 'AZ315',  13: 'OL821',  14: 'HN765',  15: 'ED589'}, 'Location': {0: 'Q1',  1: 'Q3',  2: 'Q1',  3: 'Q3',  4: 'Q3',  5: 'Q4',  6: 'Q3',  7: 'Q1',  8: 'Q2',  9: 'Q3',  10: 'Q1',  11: 'Q2',  12: 'Q1',  13: 'Q1',  14: 'Q3',  15: 'Q1'}, 'NEW': {0: 'YES',  1: 'NO',  2: 'NO',  3: 'YES',  4: 'YES',  5: 'NO',  6: 'NO',  7: 'YES',  8: 'NO',  9: 'NO',  10: 'NO',  11: 'YES',  12: 'NO',  13: 'YES',  14: 'YES',  15: 'YES'}, 'YEAR': {0: 2021,  1: 2018,  2: 2019,  3: 2021,  4: 2021,  5: 2019,  6: 2019,  7: 2021,  8: 2018,  9: 2019,  10: 2018,  11: 2021,  12: 2018,  13: 2021,  14: 2021,  15: 2021}, 'PT1': {0: '',  1: 'NOT_TESTED',  2: '',  3: 'NOT_FINISHED',  4: '',  5: '',  6: '180',  7: '',  8: '',  9: '',  10: '',  11: '',  12: 'TOO_LOW',  13: '',  14: '155',  15: ''}, 'PT2': {0: '',  1: '',  2: '',  3: '',  4: '',  5: 'TOO_LOW',  6: '',  7: '',  8: '160',  9: 'TOO_LOW',  10: '',  11: '',  12: '',  13: '',  14: '',  15: ''}, 'PT3': {0: '',  1: 'TOO_LOW',  2: '',  3: 'TOO_LOW',  4: '',  5: '',  6: '',  7: '',  8: '',  9: '',  10: '',  11: 'NOT_FINISHED',  12: '',  13: '185',  14: '',  15: '165'}, 'PT4': {0: '',  1: '',  2: '',  3: '',  4: '',  5: 165.0,  6: '',  7: '',  8: '',  9: '',  10: '',  11: '',  12: 180.0,  13: '',  14: '',  15: ''}})
```

Comment: can you provide the data in `pd.DataFrame()` format?

Comment: `pd.Dataframe({'ID': {0L: 'GF342', 1L: 'IF874', 2L: 'FH386', 3L: 'KJ190', 4L: 'TY748'}, 'Location': {0L: 'Q1', 1L: 'Q3', 2L: 'Q1', 3L: 'Q3', 4L: 'Q3'}, 'YEAR': {0L: 2021L, 1L: 2018L, 2L: 2019L, 3L: 2021L, 4L: 2021L}, 'NEW': {0L: 'YES', 1L: 'NO', 2L: 'NO', 3L: 'YES', 4L: 'YES'}, 'PT4': {0L: nan, 1L: nan, 2L: nan, 3L: nan, 4L: nan}, 'PT3': {0L: nan, 1L: 'TOO_LOW', 2L: nan, 3L: 'TOO_LOW', 4L: nan}, 'PT2': {0L: nan, 1L: nan, 2L: nan, 3L: nan, 4L: nan}, 'PT1': {0L: nan, 1L: 'NOT_TESTED', 2L: nan, 3L: 'NOT_FINISHED', 4L: nan}})`               I hope this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['NO',  'NOT_TESTED', None, 'TOO_LOW', None],
                  ['YES',  'NOT_FINISHED ', None, 'TOO_LOW', None],
                  ['YES', None, None, None, None],
                  ['NO', 180, None, None, None],
                  ['NO', 'TOO_LOW', None, None, 180],
                  ['YES', 155.6, None, None, None]], columns=['NEW', 'PT1', 'PT2', 'PT3', 'PT4'])

# Number of tested elements: 43 (and a percentage from all elements)"
# (which equates to how many rows show too_low or a value between 150 and 190)
filter_ = df.loc[:, 'PT1':'PT4']\
            .apply(lambda x: x.eq('TOO_LOW') | x.astype(str).str.fullmatch(r'\d+\.*\d*'), axis=0)\
            .any(axis=1)

number_of_tested = filter_.sum()


#"Number of new tested elements
new_tested_elements = df[filter_ & df['NEW'].eq('YES')].shape[0]


#"Number of old tested elements
old_tested_elements = df[filter_ & df['NEW'].eq('NO')].shape[0]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I get an error stating: 'AttributeError: ("'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'fullmatch'", u'occurred at index PT1')' Is this because I am using python 2.7? (I have no choice with this version as it is a constraint I have been obliged to respect)

Comment: Use `.match` then

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working with a DataFrame from the library Pandas. I had a similar problem and iterated through the dataframe. The variable df was a dataframe I extracted from a CSV with the method "read_csv" from Pandas. I don't know how do you get the dataset but it should be a similar format. I hope it works for you or at least you get an approach

```
tooLow = "TOO_LOW"
elementsCount = 0
index = len(df.columns)

for r in range(len(df.index)):
    for c in range(index):
        columnValue = df.at[r, df.columns[c]]
        if  (150 <= columnValue <= 190) or (columnValue == tooLow):
            elementsCount += 1

print("Elements satisfying criteria: ", elementsCount)
```

Comment: This approach seems to work at first but actually, it only counts the number of times too_low appears in the whole dataset. Unsure why so I'm working on it.     To clarify, each element (row) is either tested or not. It is tested if a value 150-190 appears at any point in columns TP1 to TP4. If it appears in both TP1 and TP2 for example, it is not tested twice, only once. And it is also tested if it shows too_low at some point in TP1 to TP4, regardless of what is in the other columns. So for example, if for an element shows 165 in TP1 and too_low in TP3 then this element is considered tested.